# "Error running com.example.flutter_launcher

Tags: flutter

package identifier or launch activity not found.
Please check E:\udemy_flutter\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 36):

Check android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml
the root tag (**manifest**) should contain the attribute **package** as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutterdemo">
```

(this is an example, substitute "com.example.flutterdemo" with your package name)

[image]

Comment: This should be an acceptable answer. I was looking for a solution couple of hours, with no luck. This solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to be helpful!

Comment: In my case, while using Flutter with Visual Studio, I upgraded Android Studio to Dolphin and run some migration suggested by the IDE. Somehow this `package` like disappeared in the process. Adding it back solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone explain how this happened exactly? During what process[es] will the `package="com.example.flutterdemo"` be deleted (or not defined) - does anyone know?? I had the same problem, but I need to understand how exactly this came about.

Comment: This saved my day! This is the correct answer for both android_x86 and android_x64

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and here is how I solved it:

1. Delete the `android` directory
2. Delete the `build` directory
3. In Terminal, type `flutter create .` run
4. Execute `flutter run` in terminal